# Error VBA function

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Function CC1(BP As short, CC As short) As String
    If BP = 1 Then
    cc = "B*"
      Else
    cc = "C*"
   End If
End Function
```

I tried to call the above function in access query, but if says compile error

Access query has this function in below format

```
n: CC1([BP],[CC])
```

Comment: Declare as Long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA doesn't have a data type `short`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned Short doesn't exist.

Declare as Long which can easily cater for signed 16-bit (2-byte) integers that range in value from -32,768 through 32,767.

Why Long? See the lengthy discussion here: [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

Comment: thank you :-) But I see null value when I call the same function in query

Comment: ? There is no function above. It is a datatype called Long.

Comment: If you can see my function in the question section

Answer (score 0):

***Byte*** is suitable for your function defined

`SELECT   CC1([BP],[CC]) as n`

```
Function CC1(BP As Byte, CC As Byte) As String
    If BP = 1 Then
    CC1 = "B*"
      Else
    CC1 = "C*"
   End If
End Function
```

**Note:**

1. The value to be returned must be assigned to a variable having the
   same name as the Function
2. `CC As Byte` is not used.